# How to ensure GDB terminates in command file error?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, gdbserver

I want to automate a GDB debug session using command files but want to make sure GDB terminates every time.

This is a problem as described in the documentation :

> An error in any command terminates execution of the command file and
> control is returned to the console.

In my case I want the script to either continue or terminate GDB if there is an error. I.e. dont let it return to console (and make me quit manually).  E.g. see below

```
echo Starting GDB script\n
set confirm off
set pagination off
echo Connecting to target\n
target remote localhost:1234
thread 1
thread 2 # <-- This command will produce an error, and stop the script from terminating GDB
k
q
```

Answer (score 1):

> In my case I want the script to either continue or terminate GDB if there is an error. I.e. dont let it return to console (and make me quit manually).

Invoke GDB with `-batch` argument, and it will ignore script errors.

Example:

```
$ gdb -q -batch -ex 'start' -ex 'thread 2' -ex 'print foo' -ex kill  ./a.out
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x112d

Temporary breakpoint 1, 0x000055555555512d in main ()
Unknown thread 2.
No symbol "foo" in current context.
[Inferior 1 (process 2359421) killed]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know how can I integrate ```-batch``` with a command file?

Comment: Thanks, i got it to work like this in the end ```riscv32-unknown-elf-gdb path/to/elf -batch -x path/to/command/script```